# Scraping certain data from html webpage with rvest in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am unable to scrape certain data from a YouTube video page in order to create a dataset. I had success scraping other webpages for practice, but can't seem to get it to work for my actual use case.

Specifically I am trying to fetch the username of each YouTube channel in a vector of video_ids. This can be found in the HTML of the video page when inspecting the following element:
`<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-owner-renderer" tabindex="-1" href="/user/BonAppetitDotCom"> .... </a>`

I have the below R script:

```
library(rvest)

# 3 random trending YouTube videos
videos <- c("2kyS6SvSYSE","iIxy3JN3-jc","jr9QtXwC9vc")
for (video in videos) {
  url <- paste0("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",video,"/")
  webpage <- read_html(url) #outputs a list of 2: <head> and <body> content

  #narrow down the elements to fetch what I need
  data <- html_nodes(webpage, '.ytd-video-owner-renderer a') #returns an empty list
  ...
  print(...)
}
```

The script would continue to fetch a certain element from the `data` list with `html_text` which would contain the value I need.

I also tried to fetch the element through XPath with:
`data <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath="/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[3]/ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer/div/div[2]/ytd-video-owner-renderer/a")` Which returns the same empty list.

Any idea what's wrong with my approach or if there is a better way to fetch the data I need?

Comment: Youtube does provide API, did you try that to get data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the official API which is straightforward to search for a list of videos and get its information

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
```

- Go to [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), search Youtube Data API / enable Youtube Data API v3

[image]

- Go to Credentials / Create Credentials / API key

[image]

Use the api key in the script below. This script get the channel title for all videos in `video_ids` vector :

```
library(httr)

api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
video_ids = c("2kyS6SvSYSE","iIxy3JN3-jc","jr9QtXwC9vc")

url <- modify_url("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos", 
    query = list(
        "part" = "snippet",
        "id" = paste(video_ids, collapse=","),
        "key" = api_key)
)
output <- content(GET(url), as = "parsed", type = "application/json")

#build dataframe
result <- list();
index <- 1
for(t in output$items){
    result[[index]] <- list(
        id = t$id,
        channelTitle = t$snippet$channelTitle
    )
    index <- index + 1
}
df <- do.call(rbind, result)
options(width = 1200)
print(df)
```

Output

```
     id            channelTitle                          
[1,] "2kyS6SvSYSE" "CaseyNeistat"                        
[2,] "iIxy3JN3-jc" "Cleveland Cavaliers on cleveland.com"
[3,] "jr9QtXwC9vc" "Fox Family Entertainment"
```

Checkout the `snippet` object for more information about the videos, checkout [the API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

You can also use [this library](https://github.com/soodoku/tuber) if you prefer

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I built out your script further after taking a look at the documentation. A subsequent API call now fetches the amount of subscribers based on input of the first API call. This works great with a vector of a few video ids, but I'm working with ~6300 observations. Any suggestion on doing something like this in bulk? I wasn't able to pass a vector of 6300 video ids. Does Google allow me to do such thing at all?

Comment: @Brayn I think it‘s the server limitation for the url size, given that uri should be under 2000 characters you can start bulk of 150 videos id per request (if not working try with less)